# Is it possible to pass Stack, Queue or Hashtable to an Intent?

Tags: android, .net, data-structures, xamarin, xamarin.android

We can pass data between activity. For example, getStringExtra, getIntExtra and getArraylistExtra on [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Is there any way to pass more complex data structured such as Stack, Queue, Hashtable, etc? If so, how?

Comment: thanks @Moon. sorry for my bad English...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements inside your stack or queue are implementing `Serializable`, then you can. 
Send data with:

```
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, BlahActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("data", (Serializable)data);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Where data is your queue/stack, and extract with:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
received_data=(<YOUR_COMPLEX_DATA_TYPE>)intent.getSerializableExtra("data");
```

Comment: @Chrisk8er hashtable should work the same way as long as its keys and values are serializable if i'm not wrong

Answer (score 1):

As long as your element types implement `Serializable` then you can use `getSerializableExtra()`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to put them into a List or ArrayList, then serialize with Json.NET/ServiceStack/ProtoBuf into string, put that string into the intent and on the other side deserialize it back into List.

If the activity is only meant to run from your code only, I usually just use a static Dictionary container and then push/pull with the Guid going into the string extras. This is a container for ViewModels: https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/blob/master/Core/SimplyMobile.Core/ViewModelContainer.cs

Extensions and using ViewModel approach help with pulling the data:

https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/blob/master/Android/SimplyMobile.Android/Extensions/ActivityExtensions.cs